# How to block our website in Pakistan?

Tags: .htaccess

```bash
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order deny,allow
deny from 81.52.168.0/23
deny from 188.138.10.163/32
deny from 188.138.78.129/32 
allow from all
</Limit>
```

I found some code but I not conform. 
How do I use this to block my website in Pakistan? I don’t want to open my site in this country, so can anyone tell me what I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

TCP/IP doesn't work like that: you can't really identify, much less "block countries", just by IP address.

Even if you tried to hack an .htaccess file, the list of IP addresses would be prohibitively large ... and you'd still miss many.

SUGGESTION: Read this article for several possible alternatives for you:

http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-block-entire-countries-from-accessing-website/

This is another good article:

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/easily-block-visitors-from-a-country-using-htaccess/

Comment: thanks for this article i read this article already but i not help full this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a site, [countryipblocks.net](https://www.countryipblocks.net/country_selection.php), that will generate the htaccess file for you. For the country, obviously you want to select Pakistan, then you'll want to select the ".htaccess Deny" option, then it will generate the file you need.

Comment: i create this file but can you tel me what the next step i follow .what i doing .

Comment: Again - .htaccess is probably a Bad Idea - it can bog down your server, and it will probably miss a lot of addresses.  STRONG RECOMMENDATION: 1) Configure firewall rules (if possible) 2) Use a CDN (if possible), 3) use an Apache module like MaxMind in conjunction with an (updatable!) database GeoLite2, 4) Use a combination of techniques.  .htaccess is *NOT* the answer.

Comment: so any other helping materiel for me.

Comment: @SamiaNaveed if you added that to your .htaccess file, you should be set as long as those IP addresses are valid

Comment: @paulsm4 I get that .htaccess might not be the best solution, you say that it is not the answer, and you may be right, but it is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Put in `.htaccess` file and hide t:

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST> 
order deny,
allow deny from 72.229.28.185 
allow from all
</Limit>
```